# How do I preserve the design when I change the page language؟

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, multilingual, arabic

I am maintaining a webpage to make it responsive, this page has two versions (English and Arabic),
and there are two buttons, one for the English, and other for Arabic,

When I click on the English, I have made the following style for the English version:

```
<style type="text/css">
    
   @media (min-width:0) and (max-width:607px){
     #MainContent_WebChartControl2_IMG{
       padding-right: 270px;
       
         }
 #MainContent_WebChartControl3_IMG{
       padding-right: 270px;
       
     
         }
    #MainContent_WebChartControl1_IMG{
         padding-right: 400px;
          padding-left: 90px;
          margin-top: -190px;
           margin-left: -116px;
          
    }


}


        @media (min-width: 608px)and (max-width: 768px) {
            #MainContent_WebChartControl3_IMG {
                padding-left: 140px;
                margin-left: -140px;
            }

            #MainContent_WebChartControl2_IMG {
                padding-left: 140px;
                margin-left: -140px;
            }

            #MainContent_WebChartControl1_IMG {
                padding-right: 300px;
                padding-left: 90px;
                margin-top: -100px;
                margin-left: -40px;
            }
        }

         
     @media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 791px){
    #MainContent_WebChartControl2_IMG{
         padding-left: 1px;
         margin-left: -70px;
         }
    #MainContent_WebChartControl1_IMG {
                padding-right: 70px;
                padding-left: 8px;
               
                margin-left: -70px;
            }
     

   }
     @media (min-width: 792px) and (max-width: 894px){
    #MainContent_WebChartControl2_IMG{
         padding-left: 1px;
         margin-left: -50px;
         }
    #MainContent_WebChartControl1_IMG {
                padding-right: 70px;
                padding-left: 8px;
               
                margin-left: -40px;
            }
     

   }
 
</style>
```

How can I use the same rules for the Arabic version, note that the direction in Arabic goes from right to left,
what functions, libraries or techniques should I use?

Comment: if you build your layout on flex or grid, you do not have to deal with float behavior and the whole flex/grid setup will follow the direction set from the language. idea : https://jsfiddle.net/7th9014o/

Answer (score -1):

```
float: right;   /* The element floats the right of its container. */
Text-align : right; 
p {   direction: rtl; }

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" dir="rtl">  /* in your HTML */
```

=> Use BootStrap Framework